# Are evil byteblock reinterpretations valid C++?

Tags: c++, malloc

Let us not discuss the badness of the following code, it's not mine, and I fully
agree with you in advance that it's not pretty, rather C-ish and potentially
very dangerous:

```
void * buf = std::malloc(24 + sizeof(int[3]));

char * name = reinterpret_cast<char *>(buf);
std::strcpy(name, "some name");

int * values = reinterpret_cast<int *>(name + 24);
values[0] = 0; values[1] = 13; values[2] = 42;
```

Its intent is quite clear; it's a "byte block" storing two arrays of different
types. To access elements not in front of the block, it interprets the block as
`char *` and increments the pointer by `sizeof(type[len])`.

My question is however, is it legal C++(11), as in "is it guaranteed that it
will work on every standard conforming compiler"? My intuition says it's not, however g++ and clang seem to be fine
with it.

I would appreciate a standard quote on this one; unfortunately I
was not able to find a related passage myself.

Comment: If `24 % sizeof(int) != 0` (unlikely), then this would lead to misaligned accesses, support for which is implementation-defined.

Comment: reinterpreting as `char*` is fine.

Comment: Putting the data in `buf` is OK but as @OliCharlesworth said, the `int`s may not be aligned properly.

Comment: What do you think the compiler should think about legality if you write `reinterpret_cast<int *>`?  Misaligned access can cause a hardware exception.

Comment: I would prefer `void * buf = ::operator new(sizeof(char[24]) + sizeof(int[3]));
char * name = new(buf) char[24];
int * values = new(name + 24) int[3];`, but sadly placement-array-new cannot be used portably.

Comment: @Simple: `malloc` yields a pointer that is aligned to the maximum of the fundamental type's alignment requirements. The size of the char part seems to be a multiple of `sizeof(int)` (in all platforms, not on an invented environment, but in real hardware), so the `int` s will be correctly aligned.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I would prefer `struct things { char first_things[24]; int second_things[3]; things t;`, which works not only in C++, but also in C, is perfectly portable, and man, isn't it damn simple?

Comment: So bottom line, no it's not standard conform, but it *does* work on all real life platforms.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition; so you could reduce the noise by removing that. (And you should definitely remove the second occurrence, in the arithmetic involving `char*`, since that would be wrong if it weren't 1).

Comment: You need code like this to parse network byte streams or read/write binary files.  I wouldn't call it "evil".  In this case, you could cast to a struct like R. Martinho Fernandes says, but that won't help you for a variable-length format.

Comment: @japreiss you indeed hit the field (networking) where I found this code, and it *is* using an dynamic length `int` array; I just wanted to reduce this to a minimal example; and a little polemic never hurt anyone ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly valid C++ code (not nice though, as you noted yourself). As long as the string is not longer than 23 characters, it is not even in conflict with the strict aliasing rules, because you never access the same byte in memory through differently typed pointers. However, if the string exceeds the fixed limit, you have undefined behaviour like any other out of bounds bug.

Still, I'd recommend to use a structure, at the very least:

```
typedef struct whatever {
    char name[24];
    int [3];
} whatever;

whatever* myData = new myData;
std::strcpy(myData->name, "some name");
myData->values[0] = 0; myData->values[1] = 13; myData->values[2] = 42;
```

This is 100% equivalent to the code you gave, except for a bit more overhead in the `new` operator as opposed to directly calling `malloc()`. If you are worried about performance, you can still do `whatever* myData = (whatever*)std::malloc(sizeof(*myData));` instead of using new.

Comment: @Arpegius You can only get unaligned ints if the offset is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, and do you know any platform that uses an `int` type that does not divide 24? 24 is 3*8, so you'd need an int of either 5 bytes or 16 bytes... no, there is no danger of misalignment here...

Comment: it might be nice to add that while it runs perfectly fine on any real machine, there is no guarantee that it does; there might be machines someday on which it will break, and this does not apply to "valid" code IMHO

Comment: @cmaster I just forget that malloc always return aligned to word. Mea culpa.